# Getting the info from exact header using wget

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line, wget

I need to get data from Apixu using PowerShell and wget command. So, I tried this variant

```
wget -UseBasicParsing "http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=MY_KEY&query=London"
```

and it kinda works, but not the exact way I want it to work.  The output is:

```
StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"request":{"type":"City","query":"London, United
                    Kingdom","language":"en","unit":"m"},"location":{"name":"London","country":"United
                    Kingdom","region":"City of London, Greater London","lat":"51.517","...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                    Connection: keep-alive
                    access-control-allow-methods: GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE,...
Forms             :
Headers           : {[Transfer-Encoding, chunked], [Connection, keep-alive], [x-apilayer-transaction-id], [access-control-allow-methods, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, PATCH,
                    DELETE, OPTIONS]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        :
RawContentLength  : 722
```

**So, is there a way to print value of "Content" header to console?**

Comment: `wget` in PowerShell isn't actually `wget` since it's just an alias for `Invoke-WebRequest`. Try `Invoke-RestMethod` instead, it's a little more eager to interpret results as objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the value of any single property by using `ForEach-Object -MemberName`:

```
PS ~> Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=MY_KEY&query=London" |ForEach-Object -MemberName Content
{
  "success": false,
  "error": {
    "code": 101,
    "type": "invalid_access_key",
    "info": "You have not supplied a valid API Access Key. [Technical Support: support@apilayer.com]"
  }
}
```

You can also pipe the response object directly to `ConvertTo-Json` which will construct a custom object as described by the JSON - `ConvertTo-Json` will automatically figure out to parse only the `Content` value:

```
PS ~> Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing "http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=MY_KEY&query=London" |ConvertTo-Json

success error
------- -----
  False @{code=101; type=invalid_access_key; info=You have not supplied a valid API Access Key....
```